# How to apply striped fonts to special characters?

Tags: objective-c, fonts, nsattributedstring, truetype, cs193p

I am solving assignment #6 of 2013-2014 cs103p (however is not necessary to know the details of this assignment to answer). I have to implement (not the full version of) the [set game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28game%29), and display the cards in a collection of buttons. The symbols used are ▲,●,■.

I use an attributed string to represent the color of the symbol. The shadings are solid, striped and open. For a solid and striped symbol I just change the value of `NSStrokeWidthAttributeName`, which is non zero for an open character.

Now the problem comes with a striped character. I downloaded a font to represent striped characters: [mexcellent](http://www.1001fonts.com/mexcellent-font.html). But the problem is that the stripes are applied only to regular alphabet characters, not to my symbols. How do I manage to represent these characters with stripes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the character map of the font here:
http://www.1001fonts.com/mexcellent-font.html#character-map

You can see that your symbols aren't included in this font. The system just chooses another font to render these characters.

You need to use a font which includes the desired symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if still relevant but I'm just doing now the same assignment.

I've used this attribute to make a transparent symbol as striped

```
NSForegroundColorAttributeName with [[UIColor someColor] colorWithAlphaComponent: alphaValue]
```

but it not actually doing striped symbols.